# simple query SQL

Tags: sql

I'm stuck in this query.
I need to print the laptop and the notebook with the maximum price (`art_pv`) from a table with products data(`articles`).

I can get the products data from the laptops and notebooks like this:

```
SELECT art_name, art_pv
FROM articles
WHERE art_name LIKE'%NOTEBOOK%' OR art_name LIKE '%LAPTOP%';
```

but i can't get only the most expensive laptop and notebook. Can you help me?

Comment: You cant get them because in your where clause you are not giving any clause to filter them... You need to add as Jens wrote: having max(art_pv) or you can also add a clause where the price is bigger than a given one. Ex: where art_pv > "your defined price" in order to get a result with all item having a price bigger than.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` should help you:

```
SELECT art_name, art_pv
FROM articles
WHERE art_name LIKE'%NOTEBOOK%' OR art_name LIKE '%LAPTOP%'
and art_price = (select max(art_price) FROM articles
   WHERE art_name LIKE'%NOTEBOOK%' OR art_name LIKE '%LAPTOP%')
```

or if you need from both objects the the one who have the max price you can use `union`:

```
SELECT art_name, art_pv
FROM articles
WHERE art_name LIKE'%NOTEBOOK%' 
and art_price = (select max(art_price) FROM articles
   WHERE art_name LIKE'%NOTEBOOK%')

UNION
SELECT art_name, art_pv
FROM articles
WHERE  art_name LIKE '%LAPTOP%'
and art_price = (select max(art_price) FROM articles
   WHERE  art_name LIKE '%LAPTOP%')
```

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate by the maximum of each group:

```
SELECT art_name, Max(art_pv) MaxPrice
FROM articles
WHERE art_name LIKE'%NOTEBOOK%' OR art_name LIKE '%LAPTOP%'
group by art_name;
```

Comment: I see that it shows me all the laptops and notebooks but not only the most expensive

Comment: You can't have included the group by, the above query will return 1 row for each `art_name`  (and will only ready the table *once!*) - [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc4eae07f8acf38a4f2874c8512ba2be)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this could be handled, but I believe a simple UNION could be a solution:

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT TOP 1 art_name, art_pv
FROM articles
WHERE art_name LIKE '%NOTEBOOK%'
ORDER BY art_pv DESC

UNION

SELECT TOP 1 art_name, art_pv
FROM articles
WHERE art_name art_name LIKE '%LAPTOP%'
ORDER BY art_pv DESC
```